# R: add titles to scatterplots from for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am quite new to R an can't seem to solve the following issue:

I have a dataframe with different variables (= columns), which are either predictors or targets. I want to look at the scatterplots between each predictor and each target (for computational reasons I don't want to look at all pariwise scatterplots). I wrote a nested for-loop to create the scatterplots, which works well. However, I can't add a title to the scatterplots indicating the two correlated features.

I wrote a simple example:

```
#create dataframe
f1 = rnorm(100)
f2 = rnorm(100)
f3 = rnorm(100)
t1 = rnorm(100)
t2 = rnorm(100)
mydata = data.frame(f1, f2, f3, t1, t2)

#defining targets & features by vectors
targets <- c("t1", "t2")
features <- c("f1", "f2", "f3")

#wrong solution
for (i in mydata[,features]){
 for (j in mydata[,targets]){
  plot= plot(i, j, main = paste(names(mydata)[i], "vs", names(mydata)[j]))
}}
```

This does apparently not work.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? 
Ideally, I would like to add the names of both variables to each Scatterplot and to the corresponding axis.

Comment: Please include your code as plain text, not as an image. This will make it easier for us to copy paste and reproduce on our side.

Comment: Also, try `names(mydata)[i]`, or, you know, just `features[i]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Your question is very likely going to get closed quickly if you do not do what other, good questions do and provide a reproducible example. _Nobody_ is going to type that code or OCR it for you. Help others help you.

Comment: You guys are completly right, it makes total sense to include code as actual code. I didn't know that was possible, but now I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you can, please include your minimal reproducible example in a code block, it makes it much easier for people to answer if they can copy and paste your code.

Based on your example, the reason `names(mydata[i])` doesn't work is that `i` contains all the values in the column, not a reference to the column. Also, you would typically want something more like `names(mydata)[i]` to select a single value from the names vector.

To get the names into your scatterplots, try this:

```
# Sample data
f1 <- rnorm(100)
f2 <- rnorm(100)
f3 <- rnorm(100)
t1 <- rnorm(100)
t2 <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(f1, f2, f3, t1, t2)

# Features, Targets to compare
targets <- c('t1', 't2')
features <- c('f1', 'f2', 'f3')

# The nested for loop.
for (i in features) {
  # i = 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'fn'
  for (j in targets) {
    # j = 't1', 't2', 'tn'
    p <- plot(
      df[[i]], # Reference to the dataframe column titled 'fn'
      df[[j]], # Reference to the dataframe column titled 'tn'
      main = paste(i, 'x', j), # Title using the strings
      xlab = i, # x-axis title
      ylab = j  # y-axis title
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes so much sense and works perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You only need select both features and pass it in a `paste0()` doing as following:

```
feature1<- rnorm(100)
feature2<- rnorm(100)
feature3<- rnorm(100)
target1<- rnorm(100)
target2<- rnorm(100)

mydata<- data.frame(feature1, feature2, feature3, target1, target2)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
features<- c("feature1", "feature2", "feature3")
targets<- c("target1", "target2")
for(i in 1:length(targets)){
  for(j in 1:length(features)){
    plot(mydata[,c(features[j], targets[i])], main = paste0(c(features[j], "vs",targets[i])))
  } }
```

[image]

If you wanted just to plot all variables against all variables, you could just use `plot(mydata)`

Comment: You went to all the trouble of typing his code and you didn't even answer his actual question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hope my edit makes it clearer. Cheers :)

Comment: This also works really well! Unfortunately (or luckily), I have too many variables to look at the plots of all variables against all variables. Thanks for the help:)